# How to configure internet connection in X Window System applications?

Tags: networking, putty, xming

I have to work on a Windows machine which I'm using as a client for my external RedHat machine. According to my job requirments I need to use some X window apps which are hosted on the Linux machine. For these kind of tasks I've configured a simple stack using xming and putty. It works fine, but for instance when I start Firefox it does not see any network connection and as a consequence I'm not able to use internet.

from putty:

```
ping -c4 google.com
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3023ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 17.887/18.258/18.836/0.378 ms
```

Comment: According to your ping output there is a network connection. Are you sure nothing is blocking port 80? You can test this with `telnet google.com 80` or `wget google.com`.

Comment: @mtak i'm stupid. thank you for your comment. actually yes - it's blocked. write this as answer and i'll mark it as approved answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As requested by the asker:* According to your ping output there is a network connection. Are you sure nothing is blocking port 80? You can test this with `telnet google.com 80` or `wget google.com`?